# Rivets.js adapter publish vs setting value

Tags: publish, rivets.js

Rivets.js proposes to use the `adapter.read` and `adapter.publish` functions to `get` and `set` properties of a model while defining binders. I have not found an actual benefit of using `read`/`publish` when compared to the standard `get`/`set` methodology.

Excerpt from documentation:

```
adapter.read(model, keypath)
adapter.publish(model, keypath, value)
```

The source code for `read` and `publish` from v0.6.10

```
read: function(obj, keypath) {
    return obj[keypath];
},
publish: function(obj, keypath, value) {
    return obj[keypath] = value;
}
```

I wonder if anyone knows about the benefits that read and publish may offer?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. The answer is as simple as abstracting the get and set functionalities from the binder. This has no real benefit if using rivets as is with the one and only dot (.) binder which it ships with. But this approach comes in very handy when one defines custom adapters.

A good example, like in my case, is when using the rivets-backbone adapter. The model passed to the binder could be a plain old java object or a backbone model. Reading and writing of properties on the object vary based on its type. By using the `publish` and `read` functions, this logic gets abstracted from the binders implementation.